# CSS Sliding panel from left to right

Tags: html, css

I have this code working from right to left sliding.

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.00001);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

#panel:target {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#panel">☰</a></div>
<p><a id="panel" href="#">This is the side panel.</a></p>
```

Now I like to have this sliding from left to right. I changed right:0; to left, then it is sliding from the center to the left. I did read almost all posts and tried a lot of different things but nothing worked. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want the panel to be on the extreme left of the screen or in the same position as it is now, when it is moving from right to left?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, what exactly you are looking for. But perhaps you should be using `translate` property instead of scale, though you can achieve the same using `scale` as well.

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}
#panel:target {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#panel">☰</a></div>
 <p><a id="panel" href="#">This is the side panel.</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of

> -webkit-transform-origin

Is this what you're looking for ?

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.00001);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

#panel:target {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#panel">☰</a></div>
<p><a id="panel" href="#">This is the side panel.</a></p>
```

Comment: You're welcome.
Please answer that helped you and don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" (the check mark next to the vote arrows) if you used that solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have also to change `-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;` and make it `-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;` to open it from left, check the snippet:

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.00001);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}
#panel:target {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div>
 <a href="#panel">☰</a>
</div>
<p>
  <a id="panel" href="#">This is the side panel.</a>
</p>
```

Comment: And this is working too! I tried to change the transform-origin but I started with 100% and not 0%. You guys made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You were correct to change `right` to `left`, but you also need to change the X axis of the `transform-origin` to zero:

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.00001);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

#panel:target {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#panel">☰</a></div>
<p><a id="panel" href="#">This is the side panel.</a></p>
```

Comment: Hi @Maud. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please upvote any answer that helped you and don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" (the check mark next to the vote arrows) if you used that solution. Thanks.